# Flickity with ng-repeat not adding new item

Tags: angularjs, array-push, flickity

I want to have a slider using [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) and [Angular's](http://www.angularjs.org) ng-repeat that I can push and pop items from.

It's mostly working but the problem I'm having is that new items I push onto the slider don't get appended to the end. Instead the last item in the slider just keeps getting overwritten by the next pushed item. The HTML `div` elements and Array object are being pushed onto correctly, but the slider isn't visualizing it correctly.

In my index.html code I just have a button that calls `pushItem()`. The array itself is being added to correctly and the new div items are being created correctly; it's just not displaying right in the slider as stated above.

## HTML

```
<div id="itemviewer" class="flick-gallery js-flickity">

    <div class="gallery-cell">hey hey</div>
    <div class="gallery-cell">oh yeah!</div>
    <div class="gallery-cell">here we go</div>

    <div ng-repeat="item in itemViewer" class="gallery-cell">
        Header:
        <p>{{item.text1}}</p>
        Verse:
        <p>{{item.obj1.text2}}</p>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
    $('.flick-gallery').flickity({

    })
</script>
```

## Javascript

```
$scope.pushItem = function () {
  $scope.itemViewer.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the Flickity plugin, but one problem I see is that you're not tying it into Angular using a directive.

```
angular.module('whateverMod').directive('flickity', [function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '/path/to/template/flickity.html',
      replace: true,
      scope: { items: '=' },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
         scope.$watch('items', function() {
            elem.flickity({
               //your settings
            });
         });
      }
   };
}]);
```

And then in your directive template, `flickity.html`:

```
<div class="flick-gallery">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="gallery-cell">
        Header:
        <p>{{item.text1}}</p>
        Verse:
        <p>{{item.obj1.text2}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on the array in your controller, you can use the directive like this:

```
<flickity items="itemViewer"></flickity>
```

No need for the extra script at the bottom, and now Flickity updates when there are changes.